# regular expression generation

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular express for : 
letter number letter number letter number format.
eg : `"E7R8R9"`.
Below is my code:

```
string txt = "G1R1A3";
// Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 1
string re1 = "[a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9]";

Regex r = new Regex(re1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(txt);
if (m.Success)
{
    String w1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
    Console.Write("(" + w1.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

But this code matches `"GG1R1A3"` this also.
Please help.

Comment: This is pretty basic regex. What have you tried? Did it work?

Comment: i tried [a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9].But it is not working.

Comment: This will surely work, at least for lowercase letters. What is the context? I.e. do you use java and -matches() when the searched string is only part of the string matched?

Comment: I am using C#.This is my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is searching for the pattern *anywhere within* your string. If you want to anchor it to the start (and end) of the string, use `^` and `$`:

```
    string re1 = "^[a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][0-9]$";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex written  shorter way

```
       string strRegex = @"^([A-Z]\d){3}$";

        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
        string strTargetString = @"E7R8R9";
        Match myMatch = myRegex.Match(strTargetString);
            if (myMatch.Success)
            {
                // Add your code here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches only lower case letters, but your sample uses upper case letters.

If you want to match only upper case letters, use this:

```
[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]
```

If you want to match upper and lower case letters, use this:

```
[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]
```

Comment: That would make sense if his question was why it didn't match anything. Clearly it does match the text, it just matches too much.

Comment: @Lasse: Please see the edit history of his question and the first two comments. That was all there was when I wrote my answer. So back then, it made perfect sense...

Comment: I did, but perhaps he edited something right after you saw an earlier version, then SO collapses edits, because the current version history shows the first version as having no code, and the second version as having the current code.

Comment: Exactly. And I answered to the first version you see in the edit history, i.e. the one without code. He asked why a string with **upper** case letters wasn't matched by a regex that only checked for **lower** case letters. The regex was provided in the comments of the question. Back then, I couldn't know that (1) he was using IngoreCase and that (2) the problem was something else completely...

Answer (score 0):

ibhub : your try only takes into account lower case : try to run your regex in case insensitive or use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[a-Z]`

Comment: then add \b before and after or '^' and '$' if it's on a single line